# C / C++ Library Linking with CMake

Tags: c++, c, mongodb, cmake

I need to use MongoDB C Drivers in a c++ project. I want to use CMake because the IDE i'm using is well integrated with it but the compiler doesn't recognize the MongoDB drivers

So, I've tried a couple more things and to provide you with a bit more information. I've made the following script:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(sorting)

set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "/usr/lib64")
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

pkg_search_module(MONGO REQUIRED mongoc-1.0)


message(SEND_ERROR "A ${MONGO_FOUND}")        # Error:A 1
message(SEND_ERROR "B ${MONGO_LIBRARIES}")    # Error:B ssl;crypto;rt;mongoc-1.0;bson-1.0
message(SEND_ERROR "C ${MONGO_LIBRARY_DIRS}") # Error:C /usr/lib64
message(SEND_ERROR "D ${MONGO_LDFLAGS}")      # Error:D -L/usr/lib64;-lssl;-lcrypto;-lrt;-lmongoc-1.0;-lbson-1.0
message(SEND_ERROR "E ${MONGO_LDFLAGS_OTHER}")# Error:E
message(SEND_ERROR "F ${MONGO_INCLUDE_DIRS}") # Error:F /usr/include/libmongoc-1.0;/usr/include/libbson-1.0
message(SEND_ERROR "G ${MONGO_CFLAGS}")       # Error:G -I/usr/include/libmongoc-1.0;-I/usr/include/libbson-1.0
message(SEND_ERROR "H ${MONGO_CFLAGS_OTHER}") # Error:H


include_directories(${MONGO_LIBRARY_DIRS})
include_directories(${MONGO_INCLUDE_DIRS})

#link_directories(${MONGO_LIBRARY_DIRS})
#link_directories(${MONGO_INCLUDE_DIRS})


set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}   -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(sorting ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(sorting ${MONGO_LIBRARIES})
```

When i remove all the  `message()` functions from my cmake file and try to build run the project whith the `include_directories` uncomented i get this error:

`error while loading shared libraries: libmongoc-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

When i comment the `include_directories` and uncomment `link_directories` i get this error:

`fatal error: mongoc.h: No such file or directory
 #include <mongoc.h>`

Also, just out of curiosity why is it that if i chage the name `MONGO` in `pkg_search_module` to something like `MONGODB` or `MONG` i get this error:

`Error:None of the required 'mongoc-1.0' found`

Comment: This syntax `libmongo1.0>=1.0` looks so wierd! It would look better like `libmongo1.0 >= 1.0`, and please tell me the output of `pkg-confing libmongo1.0` when you execute it in a shell.

Comment: Your `pkg-config` call and the one in the cmake file, are inconsistent!

Comment: Thank you for answreing.When i do 

`pkg-config libmongoc-1.0`  


i just don't get any output.
If i do  

`pkg-config --cflags --libs libmongoc-1.0` 

i get the following output 


`-I/usr/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/include/libbson-1.0  -L/usr/lib64 -lssl -lcrypto -lrt -lmongoc-1.0 -lbson-1.0  `

Comment: That's correct, have you tried my answer?

Comment: Yes , i have. i changed the `PKG_SEARCH_MODULE` to `PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(MONGO_DB REQUIRED libmongoc-1.0)` and also `PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(MONGO_DB REQUIRED libmongoc-1.0 >= 1.0)`. Both times i got this error:  `fatal error: mongoc.h: No such file or directory
 #include <mongoc.h>`

Comment: Did you install the mongodb development files for your distribution? What distribution are you using? Or is it a mac? or Windows?

Comment: yes i have.Actually i installed from source following the MongoDB tutorial.
 I'm using elementary OS Freya

Comment: I guess this also helps. I've inserted this line in my cmake file `message(FATAL_ERROR "Include Dirs:" ${MONGO_DB_INCLUDE_DIR})`  and got this as a result `Error:Include Dirs:MONGO_DB_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND` which seems to indicate that libmongo is not being found

Comment: I believe it's MONGO_DB_INCLUDE_DIRS.

Comment: You are right ! Still, when i corrected it to `message(FATAL_ERROR "Include Dirs:" ${MONGO_DB_INCLUDE_DIRS})` i just got : `Error:Include Dirs:`

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell cmake to link to the monog library, that is achieved by means of the

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES
```

command, in your specific case it would go right after the `ADD_EXECUTABLE` command, and exactly like

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(sorting ${MONGO_DB_LIBRARIES})
```

Also, your `PKG_SEARCH_MODULE` seems to be wrong, it seems that it should be

```
PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(MONGO_DB REQUIRED libmongoc-1.0)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have done what you sugested but it's still not working.

Answer (score 3):

I am able to compile the mongo sample code given using

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(sorting)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

include_directories(/usr/include/libmongoc-1.0 /usr/include/libbson-1.0)

find_library(MONGODB_LIBRARY mongoc-1.0)
find_library(BSON_LIBRARY bson-1.0)

add_executable(sorting ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(sorting ${MONGODB_LIBRARY} ${BSON_LIBRARY})
```

Can you try with this CMakeFiles.txt ?

BTW it exists a mongo driver c++ for c++ projects !

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I've tried your configurations  and i still can't compile the project. Both `MONGODB_LIBRARY`  and `BSON_LIBRARY` are set to `NOTFOUND`. 
I've also found that for some reason i have `MongoDB_INCLUDE_DIR` and `MongoDB_LIBRARIES` set with `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib/libmongoclient.a` respectively although i never reference them in the code.
I know there is a c++ driver but one of the requirements of the project is that it's made in C.

Comment: Please update your post with your actual CMakeLists.txt to be more clear of your current try !! 
If you have `MongoDB_INCLUDE_DIR` and `MongoDB_LIBRARIES` it means that you use `find_package(MongoDB)` in your CMakeLists  which has found the file _FindMongoDB.cmake_

Answer (score 3):

I was finally able to do it!
The environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` was being overwritten by my IDE (CLION). I set it in the IDE settings to point to the library dir and now everything works fine.
This was the configuration i used:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(sorting C)


set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "")
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

pkg_search_module(MONGO REQUIRED mongoc)

include_directories(${MONGO_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${MONGO_LIBRARY_DIRS})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)

add_executable(sorting ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(sorting ${MONGO_LIBRARIES} )
```